# Zeros of the function $g_m(x)=1+\frac{\sin(m\pi x)\cos((m+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}$

Tags: calculus

Given a positive integer $m$, consider the function
$$
g_m(x)=1+\frac{\sin(m\pi x)\cos((m+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}
$$
in the interval $(0,1)$.

**My question**: What are the zeros of $g_m$ in the interval $(0,1)$? As one can find "manually",

If $m=1$, then the zeros are $\{\frac{1}{2}\}$.

If $m=2$, then the zeros are $\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}\}$.

If $m=3$, then the zeros are $\{
\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{6}\}$.

If $m=4$, then the zeros are $\{
\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{8},\frac{2}{5},
\frac{3}{5},\frac{5}{8},\frac{4}{5},\frac{7}{8}\}$

As it seems, all the zeros are rationals. What is the pattern for general $m$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
0&\overset{\tiny\text{set}}{=}&1+\dfrac{\sin(\pi mx)\cos((m+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)+\sin(\pi mx)\cos(\pi mx+\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)+\sin(\pi mx)(\cos(\pi mx)\cos(\pi x)-\sin(\pi mx)\sin(\pi x))}{\sin(\pi x)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)\cos^2(\pi mx)+\sin(\pi mx)\cos(\pi mx)\cos(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\cos(\pi mx)(\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi mx)+\sin(\pi mx)\cos(\pi x))}{\sin(\pi x)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\cos(\pi mx)\sin((m+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\\
0&=&\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi n\right)=\cos\left(\left(n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right)\,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
0&\overset{\tiny\text{set}}{=}&\cos(\pi mx)\implies x\overset{!}{=}\dfrac{2n+1}{2m}\\
x&\in&(0,1)\iff-\dfrac{1}{2}<n<m-\dfrac{1}{2}\overset{\tiny n,m\in\mathbb{Z}}{\implies}0\leq n\leq m-1\\
n&\in&\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\}\\
0&=&\sin(2\pi n)\,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
0&\overset{\tiny\text{set}}{=}&\sin((m+1)\pi x)\implies x\overset{!}{=}\dfrac{2n}{m+1}\\
0&\overset{!}{\neq}&\sin(\pi x)\iff 2\nmid x\iff m+1\nmid n\\
x&\in&(0,1)\iff0<n<\dfrac{m+1}{2}\overset{\tiny n,m\in\mathbb{Z^+}}{\implies}m+1\nmid n\wedge 1\leq n\leq\dfrac{m}{2}\\
g_m(x)&=&0\iff x\in\left\{\dfrac{2n+1}{2m}: n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\}\right\}\cup\left\{\dfrac{2n}{m+1}:1\leq n\leq\dfrac{m}{2}\wedge n\in\mathbb{Z^+}\right\}
\end{eqnarray}
So, yes, the zero(es) have to be rational.

Answer (score 0):

Using addition theorem on the $\cos$-term in $(1)$ and for a $\sin$ term in $(2)$:

$$\begin{align}
g_m(x/\pi) &\stackrel{(1)}= 1+\frac{\sin(m x)\cos((m+1) x)}{\sin(x)} \\
&= 1+\frac{\sin(m x)\cdot\big(\cos(m x)\cos(x) - \sin(m x)\sin( x)\big)}{\sin( x)} \\
&= \frac{\sin(x) + \sin(m x)\cos(m x)\cos(x) - \sin^2(m x)\sin( x)}{\sin( x)} \\
&= \frac{\sin(x)\cos^2(mx) + \sin(m x)\cos(m x)\cos(x)}{\sin( x)} \\
&\stackrel{(2)}= \frac{\cos(mx)\sin((m+1)x)}{\sin x} \\
\end{align}$$

Then $g_m(x) = 0$ means that $\sin x\neq 0$ and

$$\cos(m\pi x)\sin((m+1)\pi x) = 0$$

1. From the $\cos$-factor: $x = \dfrac{2k+1}{2m},\qquad k\in \Bbb Z$
2. From the $\sin$-factor: $x = \dfrac{k}{m+1},\qquad k\in \Bbb Z,\quad m+1\nmid k$
   That $m+1$ must not divide $k$ (resp. that $k$ must not be a multiple of $m+1$) follows from $\sin x\neq 0$ which means that $x\notin\Bbb Z$.